# Issue while calling Controller Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two controllers called FormController and CorticonResponseController.

FormController:

[HttpPost]

public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
        {

```
        Session["CorticonServiceEndpoint"] = this.CorticonServiceEndpoint;
        Session["CorticonServiceName"] = this.CorticonServiceName;
        Session["CorticonServiceMajorVersion"] = this.CorticonServiceMajorVersion;
        Session["CorticonServiceMinorVersion"] = this.CorticonServiceMinorVersion;

        Session["payLoad"] = “Test”;

        return RedirectToAction("CorticonIndex ", “CorticonResponseController”);
    }
```

CorticonResponseController:

```
    public ActionResult CorticonIndex()
    {
        string payLoad = (string)Session["payLoad"];

        string CorticonServiceEndpoint = (string)Session["CorticonServiceEndpoint"];
        string CorticonServiceName = (string)Session["CorticonServiceName"];
        string CorticonServiceMajorVersion = (string)Session["CorticonServiceMajorVersion"];
        string CorticonServiceMinorVersion = (string)Session["CorticonServiceMinorVersion"];

        var viewModel = this.Model.GetViewModel(payLoad);


        return View ("Default", viewModel);
    }
```

Here, I was sending some information from FormController to CorticonResponseController. In CorticonResponseController, I made some calculations and returning the view with the model. 
Hence the URL is changing from http://localhost:35583/banking/open-an-account To http://localhost:35583/banking/open-an-account/CorticonIdex.

However, I don’t want to change the URL so I have modified my code as below.

CorticonResponseController:

```
   public void CorticonIndex()
    {
        string payLoad = (string)Session["payLoad"];

        string CorticonServiceEndpoint = (string)Session["CorticonServiceEndpoint"];
        string CorticonServiceName = (string)Session["CorticonServiceName"];
        string CorticonServiceMajorVersion = (string)Session["CorticonServiceMajorVersion"];
        string CorticonServiceMinorVersion = (string)Session["CorticonServiceMinorVersion"];

        var viewModel = this.Model.GetViewModel(payLoad);
        TempData["ResponseController"] = viewModel;
    }
```

FormController:

```
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
    {

        Session["CorticonServiceEndpoint"] = this.CorticonServiceEndpoint;
        Session["CorticonServiceName"] = this.CorticonServiceName;
        Session["CorticonServiceMajorVersion"] = this.CorticonServiceMajorVersion;
        Session["CorticonServiceMinorVersion"] = this.CorticonServiceMinorVersion;

        Session["payLoad"] = “Test”;

        CorticonResponseController obj = new CorticonResponseController();
        obj.CorticonIndex();


        CorticonResponseModel viewModel = (CorticonResponseModel)TempData["ResponseController"];

        string controllerName = DecisionServiceProgram.GetResponseWidgetName();

        return View("Default", viewModel);
    }
```

Here,In my FormController, I was calling CorticonResponseController method and  getting CorticonResponseModel data using TempData and then returning the view.

I am facing the issues while executing the controller.

Can someone help me how to resolve the issue?

Comment: If you post data, then your `Index` will need `[HttpPost]` above it

Comment: Hi, I have modified the question. Please check the same.